# Install Package From Upstream

Tags: apache2

I am trying to install latest version of Apache2 (2.4.52) without compiling from source and all that headache. I saw Ubuntu CVE and there is this version available but in Upstream I tried to do Pin install but that's not working.

**/etc/apt/apache2**::

```
Package: apache2
Pin: version 2.4.52
Pin-Priority: 990
```

**Ubuntu Version**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

But still **apt upgrade** or **apt-get upgrade** can't find this new version

[image]

Comment: Unless the version already exists in the official repositories (it doesn't) or provided as a Snap or Flatpak (it isn't) or provided by a PPA (???) then you must compile it from source.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details - your paste shows the fix is available; but without release details how are we to know what your actual issue is.  Your paste shows the version where the fix is backported for each release.

Comment: but according to CVE its already there in UPSTREAM why can't we access it directly from there ?

Comment: The paste shows what package for each release contains the relevant fix (back-ported).   You've not provided your release details so we can't know which applies to your system.

Comment: @guiverc edited my ubuntu detail... pls check again

Comment: 2.48.48.3.1... contains the fix for *impish* or 21.10 as per your paste.   Fixes get back-ported to the version already existing in the repository; the table tells you what package for each release **contains** the CVE fix listed in the page.

Comment: @guiverc correct I am only getting 2.4.48 from impish

Comment: That contains your fix - the fix is **back-ported** to the versions in that table; ie. you have the fix already as per the document you provided fixing CVE-2021-44790 with that package.

Answer (score 4):

Fixes for **CVE-2021-44790**

are available for these releases provided in your table on https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-44790

That means the package `2.4.48-3.1ubuntu3.2` available for Ubuntu 21.10 contains the fix you're after.

Packages are **not** upgraded to later versions; fixes get back-ported to the existing packages (*unless it's more work to backport what's required & re-test, compared to just using a newer package & re-testing everything impacted by the upgraded package - that is rare*)

Comment: Thank you so much... now it make sense to me

Comment: You're more welcome.